# Custom WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text-editor

I am so sick of WYSIWYG editors being exclusively for the latest browser or being huge with every option under the sun. I tried to make my own, using code I found online as well as a little of my own handy work.

This is what I came up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/RRBHw/1/

```
/*
 * WYSIWYG EDITOR BASED ON JQUERY RTE
 */

// define the rte light plugin
(function ($) {

    if (typeof $.fn.rte === "undefined") {

        var defaults = {
            max_height: 350
        };

        $.fn.rte = function (options) {

            $.fn.rte.html = function (iframe) {
                return iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
            };

            // build main options before element iteration
            var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

            // iterate and construct the RTEs
            return this.each(function () {
                var textarea = $(this);
                var iframe;
                var element_id = textarea.attr("id");

                // enable design mode
                function enableDesignMode() {

                    var content = textarea.val();

                    // Mozilla needs this to display caret
                    if ($.trim(content) === '') {
                        content = '<br />';
                    }

                    // already created? show/hide
                    if (iframe) {
                        console.log("already created");
                        textarea.hide();
                        $(iframe).contents().find("body").html(content);
                        $(iframe).show();
                        $("#toolbar-" + element_id).remove();
                        textarea.before(toolbar());
                        return true;
                    }

                    // for compatibility reasons, need to be created this way
                    iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                    iframe.frameBorder = 0;
                    iframe.frameMargin = 0;
                    iframe.framePadding = 0;
                    iframe.height = 200;
                    if (textarea.attr('class')) iframe.className = textarea.attr('class');
                    if (textarea.attr('id')) iframe.id = element_id;
                    if (textarea.attr('name')) iframe.title = textarea.attr('name');

                    textarea.after(iframe);

                    var doc = "<html><head>" + "</head><body class='frameBody'>" + content + "</body></html>";
                    tryEnableDesignMode(doc, function () {
                        $("#toolbar-" + element_id).remove();
                        textarea.before(toolbar());
                        // hide textarea
                        textarea.hide();

                    });

                }

                function tryEnableDesignMode(doc, callback) {
                    if (!iframe) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    try {
                        iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
                        iframe.contentWindow.document.write(doc);
                        iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                    if (document.contentEditable) {
                        iframe.contentWindow.document.designMode = "On";
                        callback();
                        return true;
                    } else if (document.designMode !== null) {
                        try {
                            iframe.contentWindow.document.designMode = "on";
                            callback();
                            return true;
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    }
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        tryEnableDesignMode(doc, callback);
                    }, 500);
                    return false;
                }

                function disableDesignMode(submit) {
                    var content = $(iframe).contents().find("body").html();

                    if ($(iframe).is(":visible")) {
                        textarea.val(content);
                    }

                    if (submit !== true) {
                        textarea.show();
                        $(iframe).hide();
                    }
                }

                // create toolbar and bind events to it's elements
                function toolbar() {
                    var tb = $("<div class='rte-toolbar' id='toolbar-" + element_id + "'><div>\
                <p>\
                    <a href='#' class='bold'>Bold</a>\
                    <a href='#' class='italic'>Italic</a>\
                    <a href='#' class='unorderedlist'>List</a>\
                </p></div></div>");

                    $('.bold', tb).click(function () {
                        formatText('bold');
                        return false;
                    });
                    $('.italic', tb).click(function () {
                        formatText('italic');
                        return false;
                    });
                    $('.unorderedlist', tb).click(function () {
                        formatText('insertunorderedlist');
                        return false;
                    });

                    $(iframe).parents('form').submit(function () {
                        disableDesignMode(true);
                    });


                    var iframeDoc = $(iframe.contentWindow.document);

                    var select = $('select', tb)[0];
                    iframeDoc.mouseup(function () {
                        setSelectedType(getSelectionElement(), select);
                        return true;
                    });

                    iframeDoc.keyup(function () {
                        setSelectedType(getSelectionElement(), select);
                        var body = $('body', iframeDoc);
                        if (body.scrollTop() > 0) {
                            var iframe_height = parseInt(iframe.style.height, 10);
                            if (isNaN(iframe_height)) iframe_height = 0;
                            var h = Math.min(opts.max_height, iframe_height + body.scrollTop()) + 'px';
                            iframe.style.height = h;
                        }
                        return true;
                    });
                    return tb;
                }

                function formatText(command, option) {
                    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
                    try {
                        iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand(command, false, option);
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
                }

                function setSelectedType(node, select) {
                    while (node.parentNode) {
                        var nName = node.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                        for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
                            if (nName == select.options[i].value) {
                                select.selectedIndex = i;
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        node = node.parentNode;
                    }
                    select.selectedIndex = 0;
                    return true;
                }

                function getSelectionElement() {
                    if (iframe.contentWindow.document.selection) {
                        // IE selections
                        selection = iframe.contentWindow.document.selection;
                        range = selection.createRange();
                        try {
                            node = range.parentElement();
                        } catch (e) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Mozilla selections
                        try {
                            selection = iframe.contentWindow.getSelection();
                            range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
                        } catch (e) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        node = range.commonAncestorContainer;
                    }
                    return node;
                }

                // enable design mode now
                enableDesignMode();

            }); //return this.each

        }; // rte

    } // if

    $(".rte-zone").rte({});

})(jQuery);
```

Can anyone give me some feedback on my work? Is there any room for improving or refactoring? It seems to work in every browser I tried which I am pretty happy with a degrades gracefully if JavaScript is not enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Just three quick notes about clean code, not a complete review:

1. You could extract out some functions which would make some comments unnecessary, like:

   ```
   // IE selections
   // Mozilla selections
   ```

   Just create functions for them, like `ieSelections` and `mozillaSelections`.
2. I'd introduce an explanatory variable here:

   ```
   if (iframe.contentWindow.document.selection) ...
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   var isInternetExplorer = iframe.contentWindow.document.selection;
   if (isInternetExplorer) ...
   ```

   Reference: *Chapter 6. Composing Methods*, *Introduce Explaining Variable* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler:

   > Put the result of the expression, or parts of the expression, 
   >   in a temporary variable with a name that explains the purpose.

   And *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*.
3. This comment also seems unnecessary:

   ```
   // enable design mode now
   enableDesignMode();
   ```

   The name of the function also says that.